# Mocking dbContext vs Repository

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework

I use entity framework with Repository Pattern. while searching for means of writing unit test cases that run isolated from the database I found some people mocking the database context and others mocking the repository pattern. I wonder what's the difference? and which is better?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to mock the dbContext so that you can test the dbContext, or so that you can test your Repository, or whether you want to test your code upstream from your repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a rule about mocking. *Don't mock what you don't own*.

*Dbcontext* is an implementation detail and it should be treated as such. With *isolation*.

On the first place, it's a dependency we know nothing about its innards so we can not mock it up properly with a high degree of certainty. And certainty (alongside with confidence) is what we want to build with tests.

In line with the arguments above, once the mock is created, it will be introduced into the dependency tree; allowing more components to interact with it. If we haven't mocked adequately, such interactions might cause the test to fail due to inadequate responses or behaviours of the mock.

On the second place, it's likely mocking the dependency will take us to expose our testing code to the library' implementation details (concrete classes, interfaces, methods, etc); coupling (even more) the testing code to the library. Testing code is as important as production code and we should treat both alike because coupling has the very same bad effects on both codes.

Finally, as @Martin says, we mock the repository because we are testing code which depends on the repository. If that's the case, then the focus should be on testing that code and only that code. If we mock the `DBcontext` instead, we will end up testing two well-differentiated components with two well-segregated responsibilities (the business-specific code and the repository) at the same time. That's not bad per se, but when it comes to "unit" tests, it will cause us to lose the purpose of the test. Add the fact that we humans are terrible at focusing on several things at the same time and you get a recipe for the failure.

Summarising, if you are testing business-specific rules that depends on data access, mock the immediate abstraction to the data access; the repository. If you need test specific rules within the repository you have two options: #1. Build an integration test. #2. Isolate the logic under test. If it's not strictly related to the persistence, decouple such code from the repository and test it aside.

Answer (score 0):

> which is better?

"It depends" - there's no one answer to this that fits all contexts.

> what's the difference?

As you reduce the number of unstable dependencies that contribute to the outcome of a test, you improve the measure of the test subject itself.

One of the problems that occurs when we write lots of tests, is that in some future release we decide to change the *behavior* of some element of the system, and those changes ripple outwards and cause a bunch of changes to the observed behavior of the system.  That in turn lead to a lot of "broken" tests, that then need extra work.

Test doubles (which includes mocks) are a kind of bulkhead that you can use to protect the test from irrelevant changes.

Of course, a test that measures how well its subject interacts with a mock is *not* testing how well its subject interacts with a "real" implementation.  So there's a trade off there.

A test that mocks the "repository" is insulated from later changes to repository behaviors, but also doesn't catch errors in the integration of the repository and the test subject.  Neither choice is wrong - but one or the other might be a better fit for purpose.

(Note: "unit-test" is a somewhat confused term; I think you will get different answers depending on which definition is being assumed.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your context. Usually a repository has a dependency to a database in one way or another
(repository -> database, you should always build an abstraction layer over such a technical detail though)

If you want to unit test the repository you should mock the database, if you want to test a class that has a dependency to the repository then you should mock the repository.

Comment: true, but mocking a dbContext is easier IMO. imagine if you have a function that knows how to fetch data based on multiple includes. how would you mock that? only a mock on the dbContext level would work, right?

Comment: @Myonaiz if you are testing includes, then you are testing EF. If you are testing EF, then go with an in-memory database. Microsoft themselves recommend that: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/#unit-testing. If you are testing business logic, then put the includes in a repository and mock the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it comes down to abstraction layers, what you want to test and how long you want to spend figuring out how to mock things :-)

I’m guessing that what you really have is a Service class with an injected repository/unit of work, which in turn has a dbContext injected?

You can build tests with a real db connection and being very careful to rollback and seed. This is really slow to run and hard to do async tests without getting thread exceptions.

Your next step up, and one we used for a long time, is to replace the real database with an in memory one; we used EffortDB. This lets you check to a certain extent that any low level things you’re depending on like unique keys are working. But it is again very slow and you need to be careful with seeding. You can trash and reseed for every test, but again expensive.

The next step up is to mock the dbContext and dbset that your Repository is using. This can be tricky as you need to really understand what Linq statements are doing behind the scenes. Async calls need a fair bit of code too.

However, you probably don’t need any of this. In the layers where you need to test your business logic the DbContext and Repository should be irrelevant. All you should care about is whether you got an object back or if it failed and threw an exception; this you can do by mocking the Repository methods.

Initially it feels very strange to not care what the database is doing, but you have think of it as being replaceable, whether this is by different ORM, going NoSQL or using text files. If you lean too heavily on the ORM or let its abstraction leak into other layers of the code it only gets painful.

Comment: your guess is true. I think the end to end testing using a database would not work in a CI/CD environment, right? could you elaborate more on your statement "If you lean too heavily on the ORM or let its abstraction leak into other layers of the code it only gets painful" ? thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: You can end up relying on the database to enforce business rules rather than this happening within your core application. Unique keys is a an easy one to point to. The other one that I've been painfully learning about is relying on the use of database generated Ids in your application layer. Uncle Bob's "Clean Architecture" book is really good at desribing the "Onion" architecture. There's a good code example from [eShopOnWeb](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb).

Comment: You can run end to end testing in a CI/CD; it just takes a long time. If you follow the "Onion" architecture, you get a 3 project split: Infrastructure, where you put all the database, mail server, external web calls; Application: where you put your business logic and model; Web: where you drop all the Controllers, viewmodels. etc. Each of these projects can have their own unit test project. The Web and Application can be made to run very fast to the point of continuous testing. Infrastructure you could set up to run infrequently, it's likely to change slower than the other projects.